# Installed gnome-shell and then removed it and went back to unity, running apt-get autoremove threatens to uninstall these packages.

Tags: unity, apt, gnome, package-management, uninstall

At first I accidentally ran `sudo apt-get remove gnome` instead of gnome-shell. This made the computer run into a boot loop. I got it fixed by installing gnome-desktop again.

I removed the gnome-shell but autoremove deleted a list of applications similar to this list. I got the bootloop error again, which I fixed again by installing gnome-desktop

Again running `sudo apt full-upgrade` gives this list. Should I do it or not?

```
  argyll argyll-ref browser-plugin-gnash finger gdebi gdebi-core
  gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0 gir1.2-caribou-1.0 gir1.2-gck-1 gir1.2-gcr-3
  gir1.2-gdesktopenums-3.0 gir1.2-gdm-1.0 gir1.2-gkbd-3.0
  gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-gweather-3.0
  gir1.2-mutter-3.0 gir1.2-networkmanager-1.0 gir1.2-nmgtk-1.0
  gir1.2-polkit-1.0 gir1.2-rest-0.7 gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12
  gir1.2-telepathylogger-0.2 gir1.2-tracker-1.0 gir1.2-upowerglib-1.0
  gir1.2-xkl-1.0 gir1.2-zpj-0.0 gjs gnash gnash-common gnome-backgrounds
  gnome-color-manager gnome-games gnome-nettool gnome-online-miners
  gnome-shell-common hamster-applet hamster-indicator
  libboost-program-options1.58.0 libcaribou-common libcaribou0 libdiscid0
  libgdm1 libgfbgraph-0.2-0 libjemalloc1 librygel-core-2.6-2
  librygel-renderer-2.6-2 librygel-renderer-gst-2.6-2 librygel-server-2.6-2
  libsofia-sip-ua-glib3 libsofia-sip-ua0 libtracker-control-1.0-0
  libtracker-miner-1.0-0 libwnck-common libwnck22 libzapojit-0.0-0
  python-appindicator python-notify python-wnck rygel rygel-playbin
  rygel-preferences sound-juicer telepathy-rakia unoconv
```